# Is it possible to automatically pretty print json on REPL with play?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

While working on scala REPL with Play Json support(play.api.libs.json), it possible to specify that all REPL output of JsValues should be automatically formatted?

e.g. By specifying another formatter via implicits

I know `Json.prettyPrint` does JSON pretty on Play, I was interested to know if there is a mechanism, either in play.json to specify a formatter to be used on toString, or if there is a Scala 2.10 construct I can use to automatically wrap every call with minimal or preferably no overhead to the calls.

Comment: Which version of Play ?

Comment: And what is actually reason you want/need to prettify your JSON ?

Comment: @biesior Play 2.1. I'm experimenting with Play JSON support and think it is clearer to me to see the results if formatted.

Comment: I was thinking I could do it with :wrap, but it was removed on scala 2.10

Answer (score 1):

Probably in Play 2.1+ with Scala there `Json.prettyPrint` should work (can't confirm now, have no any Scala project atm, but [doc says that](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson)).

On the other hand, if only destination for prettifying the JSON is possibility  to check it *'with your own eyes'* I'd rather suggest to leave it in compressed form, and then use some browser plugin to display it in prettified version, it also validates the code, allows to fold the sections etc. ie this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

What's most important you still save your transfer as just source JSON is still compressed ;)

Comment: Json.prettyPrint works but not as I asked: automatically. e.g. by wrapping every toString of JsValues.

Comment: your second comment for question arrived with delay ;) for validating purposes use mentioned plugin it's far better then only prettifying the code